# How to replace information in already existing node, without losing it's children?

Tags: java, insert, binary-search-tree

So I've implemented a Binary Search Tree and I have managed an insert-method that works. All the nodes contain information about courses with coursecode, coursename and coursecredits.
Say that I want to insert a new node that has the same key (coursecode) but different coursecredits, then it doesn't add up. It seems that my tree loses the children of the node i changed.

I've tried to write "node" instead of "root" for the case when the keys are equal, but then it lose the children like I said before.

```
public void insert(String courseCode, String courseName, double courseCredits) {
    BSTNode node = new BSTNode(courseCode, courseName, courseCredits);  
    root = insert(root, node);  
}

private BSTNode insert(BSTNode root, BSTNode node) {
    if (root==null) {
        return node;
    } else {
        String currentKey = root.getCourseCode();
        BSTNode left = root.getLeftChild();
        BSTNode right = root.getRightChild();
        if (node.getCourseCode().compareTo(currentKey) < 0) {
            left = insert(left, node);
        } else if (node.getCourseCode().compareTo(currentKey) > 0) {
            right = insert(right, node);  //Ändrade "left" till "right" i parentesen.
        } else {
            return root; 
        }

        root.setChildren(left, right);
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the question you ask abut "insert a new node". In the title you ask about editing and existing node. For the first, you need to edit the graph. For the second you need to edit the node. Please clarify and post [mcve].

Comment: Well, my graph is correct, but I want to be able to "overwrite" the existing node with the new one if they got the same key (coursecode). 
I just thought it would be easier to do it inside the insert-method.

Comment: Editing an existing node is different from inserting a new one. All you need is a setter in `BSTNode` class and use it: `node.setCourseCredits(5);` . "I just thought it would be easier to do it inside the insert-method" I wouldn't recommend it. Have methods do only one thing.

Comment: Ok, but why isn't it possible from inside the insert-method? (I believe you, I just want to understand)
What is the best way to make a setter like that?

Comment: I think I got it to work now, so thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `courseName` and `courseCredits`of the current node:

```
...
if (root==null) {
    root.setCourseName(node.getCourseName());
    root.setCourseCredits(node.getCourceCredits());
    return node;
} else {
    ...
    } else {
        root.setCourseName(node.getCourseName());
        root.setCourseCredits(node.getCourceCredits());
        return root; 
    }
    ...
```